# Java Sockets : What IP address should I use?

Tags: java, sockets, client, chat, server

I am making a java chat application with a server and client. I have the code working when I connect the client to the server using 127.0.0.1 and port 1234, but when i change the IP to my actual IP address, it doesn't seem to work. Could anyone tell me what IP I should use and how to get it, to make sure I am using the correct address.

Comment: Can you tell as the exception which you get??

Comment: Connection timed out:

Comment: Have you tried "localhost" instead?

Comment: yes but i'm trying to use my global IP so I can connect from different PC's

Comment: Which Operating System are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On command line, try

```
ipconfig /all
```

and search for the interface which are you using. There you will find the ip your are searching for.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by interface?

Comment: No problem! Please check as answered the question, if it work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running a port that isn't blocked. 80 is a good bet